# how to use fgetscsv with a csv file to parse the file into an array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

ok so ive been trying to get this to work for hours now and cant figure it out. Ive got a csv file in the format of

```
item 1, item 1 stuff
item 2, item 2 stuff
item 3, item 3 stuff
item 4, item 4 stuff
```

and im trying to parse it into an array using fgetscsv.

```
$file = fopen('test.csv', 'r');
    while (($MyCSVArray = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {

    print_r($MyCSVArray);
}
fclose($file);
```

I would really rather parse it into an associative array so i can index it like so

```
MyCSVArray[item 1]
```

which would output

```
item 1 stuff
```

However the problem I am having is that since there isnt a comma after every value it groups item 1 stuff with item 2 like so

```
MyCSVArray[0] = item 1
MyCSVArray[1] = item 1 stuff item 2
MyCSVArray[2] = item 2 stuff item 3
```

Maybe I dont understand csv files or the csv function, but I really need this to work the way I want and dont understand how to make it work and am about to  smash my face into my keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the data like you are and set the value into a new associative array as desired

```
$new_array = array()
$file = fopen('test.csv', 'r');
while (($MyCSVArray = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    $new_array[$MyCSVArray[0]] = $MyCSVArray[1];
}
fclose($file);

var_dump($new_array);
```

To the second part of your problem, it seems like you might not have proper end of line characters in your file if items from the next row are being grouped with the items from previous row.

Comment: thanks for the reply. hmm. Im exporting the data from an excel file to a csv. I would think the end of line characters would be there. But maybe not

Comment: ok figured it out. I had opened the csv file in my text editor and when I did that i guess it stripped those new line characters. works just fine now. thanks for your help!